# Unable to change the color of Seaborn Visualisation

Tags: python, output, seaborn, data-visualization

Pls can you help me out with this:
So I am following a colour theme for my EDA notebook. Despite setting the style and colour, one of my seaborn visualisations is acting funny and not showing up in the colour that I want the output in. Pls, can you help me out with the same.
Here's the code related to the issue:

```
#Lets set the style of all our seaborn based plots
plt.style.use(['ggplot'])
# Setting the theme of our plots
theme = ["#0a2e36", "#27FB6B","#14cc60","#036d19","#09a129"]
print('THEME')
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(theme))
palette= sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(theme))
```

[image: Palette Image]

Then I ran the following code for the visualisation:

```
    #The pair plot function creates a grid of Axes in which each variable in the data is shared across a single row and a single column on the y-axis.
sns.pairplot(data_df,palette="theme");
```

Despite this I am getting ablue colored pairplot.
[image: Seaborn Output Image]

Comment: Probably the `pairplot` without `hue` ignores the palette, but uses a single color.  Seaborn takes these colors from matplotlib's default colors.  You can use `sns.set_palette('theme')` to set your own colors. But be aware that `pairplot` will only use the first color (the dark `'#0a2e36'` in this case) together with alpha.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, when I run this notebook on jupyter on my system, the output is a pair-plot of the colour '#0a2e36'...And this is completely fine because the colour matches the theme of the notebook. 
The anomaly described above is showing up in Kaggle where I wanted to submit the notebook under a contest. 
Is there any other way that can force the colour on the plot?

Comment: Seaborn's creator, Michael Waskom, suggests using the keywords for the main and the diagonal subplots:  `sns.pairplot(..., plot_kws={'color': '#14cc60'}, diag_kws={'color': '#14cc60'})`.

Comment: Awesome! This actually sorted the issue. Thanks, @JohanC for tuning in and helping me out. Yes, also convey my thanks to Mr Waskom too. 
Have a great day